# Tag merge: Keyboard and Shortcuts

Tags: discussion, tagging

There is well established but sometimes (*e.g. by me*) forgotten tag: [keyboard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard).

It's tag-wiki is also written and it says that [shortcuts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortcuts) is in fact under it's scope.

> [...] Questions about built-in and custom keyboard shortcuts, [...]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course they should be merged under [keyboard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) name.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so, there are so many questions about keyboard shortcuts that we should split [keyboard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) on pieces.